# No way to resolve 'JNI_CreateJavaVM' error

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, sts

I am getting JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol error in STS 3.

My environment is MAC OS M2, Apple Chip, Java-11, STS 3.9.18 version.

and what i did

1. Set -vm/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java in Info.plist of STS3 file
2. export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home in ~/.zshrc
   Set export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
3. Reinstall STS3
4. Reinstall Java11
5. Reinstall MAC OS

Is there any other way to solve the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol error?

Comment: The STS and Java versions must both be for Intel or both for Apple Chips - you can't mix them. I don't think there is a version of STS 3 for Apple so you need the x86_64 Java